# Cassandra: Which schema for table-like mappings?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, schema

I have tried different approaches but I can't find a solution to my problem:
My data is table-like, meaning I have one data point (float) for each combination of inputs from a set of Strings:

```
(a mapping of S × S → ℝ )
```

I want to model the schema so that I can do the following lookups:

- all pairs of strings with a value in a certain range
- for a given input String, all Strings for which the mapped value is in certain range
- for a given combination of input Strings the mapped value

Since the mapping is symmetrical (`m(x,y) == m(y,x)` ), it would be great if I only had to store the
`n*(n+1) / 2` unique values instead of the `n^2` total mappings.

What I have tried so far:

1. S1+" "+S2 as row key and the value as column name
2. S1 as row key and a Composite key of [S2:value] as column name
3. S1 as row key, S2 as column name, value as column value.

but unfortunately, all these approaches don't let me do all the queries I need.
Is this even possible in Cassandra?

Comment: how big is the set S? And how many expected unique values?

Comment: S is about 10000 items at the moment, but I would like to add columnfamilies with bigger sets (30k - 100k) later on. For the unique values: They are all in the range [0,1], but every value therein could come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra does not support your first query --- *all pairs of strings with a value in a certain range* --- since currently, Cassandra only allows range queries with at least one `EQ` on the `WHERE` clause.  However, your second and third queries is doable :)

---

**Example**

Consider the following example:

```
cqlsh:so> desc table string_mappings;
CREATE TABLE string_mappings (
  s1 ascii,
  s2 ascii,
  value float,
  PRIMARY KEY (s1, s2, value)
)
```

and we have the following tuples:

```
cqlsh:so> select * from string_mappings;

 s1    | s2    | value
-------+-------+-------
 hello | hello |     1
 hello | world |   0.2
 stack | hello |     0
 stack | stack |     1
 stack | world |     0
 world | world |     1
```

Your first query does not work as Cassandra currently not support range queries without an `EQ` on the `WHERE` clause:

```
cqlsh:so> select * from string_mappings where value>0.5;
Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY part value cannot be restricted (preceding part s2 is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)
```

However, the following range query (your second query) is fine since it has an `EQ`:

```
cqlsh:so> select * from string_mappings where value > 0.5 and s2='hello' allow filtering;

 s1    | s2    | value
-------+-------+-------
 hello | hello |     1
```

and remember to put the `ALLOW FILTERING` keyword, or you will get the following error:

```
cqlsh:so> select * from string_mappings where value > 0.5 and s2='hello';
Bad Request: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING
```

Finally, your third query is also not a problem :)

```
cqlsh:so> select * from string_mappings where S1='hello' and S2='world';

 s1    | s2    | value
-------+-------+-------
 hello | world |   0.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations! As cql abstracts away the underlying cassandra data model, I tried your schema and it turns out, cassandra creates a column family exactly like my 2nd attempt :)